# I want to Cache Docker's Yarn to speed up Build with Azure Pipelines

Tags: docker, caching, dockerfile, azure-pipelines, yarnpkg

The following is specified

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: "yarn start"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.16.3
WORKDIR /app
COPY app/package.json .
COPY app/yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install
COPY . /app .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD yarn start
```

azure-pipelines-ci.yml

```
variables:
  YARN_CACHE_FOLDER: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.yarn

steps:
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'yarn | "$(Agent.OS)" | yarn.lock'
    restoreKeys: |
       yarn | "$(Agent.OS)"
       yarn
    path: $(YARN_CACHE_FOLDER)
- script: |
    docker-compose up -d
```

However, the cache is working, but Docker build speed remains the same
How can I make it work?